# CPU overheating while stresstesting GPU

Tags: cpu, gpu, cooling

I have a GTX570 and a i5-3570k processor. Lately, I've been having problems with games randomly crashing and my pc rebooting while playing them. I've encountered a weird problem: while running a GPU-stress test (FurMark) my cpu seems to overheat. After about 10 minutes, my GPU as well as my CPU reach about 82-83 degrees celcius. Around this point my pc reboots, when it restarts I get the error message: "CPU over temp problem". Which is weird since I'm not stressing my CPU...

What could the possible causes for this be? I've just cleaned the case/fans, so dust shouldn't be an issue. I suspect it might be the case/airflow? Or is it something else?

Edit: I've just run a CPU test. It stabilized around 82 degrees with peaks of 84-85 degrees. This didn't cause my pc to reboot.

Comment: the i5-3570k  is ivy bridge , there is a gpu on the same cpu package, and while furmark does minimal stress to a cpu it does use cpu. Determine for fact which gpu is in play to begin with. And at any rate adress the cpu itself reguardless.  Check your seating and thermal goop on the cpu sync.  When going through the process, a person would generally solidify thier cpu and cooling first anyways, use prime or intelburn or something and get that right first. Analising case flow would also be useful, but it might be deeper than that. Voltage increase Up the amperages very quickly, if that was done

Comment: I've just run a CPU test. It stabilized around 82 degrees with peaks of 84-85 degrees. This didn't cause my pc to reboot. So it might be something else? Not sure..

Comment: How would you describe the "reboot"? because it isnt closing out normally and shutting down is it?  A better description of "reboot" might be in order.

Comment: It immediately powers off and then starts again. When starting up it doesn't boot like normally, but shows an error in the bios startup screen, saying "CPU over temp problem".

Comment: Ahh, well that could even be a power issue, or overheating OTHER components on the motherboard. it opens up many more possiblities. although starting with these 80+ max temps on the cpu is not where I would start.

Comment: Is there any way to find out which component it is?

Comment: there are ways to check temps on more things, with a IR temp probe.  but again, there are many possible things beyond that even.  The "root access" chat room is open with many brains.

Answer (score 2):

Do you overclock? Starting with the 3rd Generation of the i CPUs, Intel changed the thermal interface material inside the CPU which causes more heat. Increase the CPU fan speed to cool the CPU more:

> Ivy Bridge's temperatures are reportedly 10°C higher compared to Sandy
>   Bridge when overclocked, even at default voltage setting.Impress
>   PC Watch (Japanese) performed experiments that confirmed earlier
>   speculations that this is because Intel used a poor quality (and
>   perhaps lower cost) thermal interface material (thermal paste, or
>   "TIM") between the chip and the heat spreader, instead of the fluxless
>   solder of previous generations.The mobile Ivy Bridge
>   processors are not affected by this issue because they do not use a
>   heat spreader between the chip and cooling system.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge_%28microarchitecture%29#Thermal_performance_and_heat_issues

Comment: I'm not overclocking.

Comment: which CPU cooler do you use?

Comment: I'm using the stock cooler

Comment: ok this explains it. The stock cooler is bad. Buy a better one like the **Thermalright Macho**